# Why does a GraphView omit the 0th vertex?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am using the latest version of graph_tool installed in it's own conda environment, as per the [installation guide](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#conda).

I ran into some perplexing behavior with this library recently. When I run the following code:

```
import graph_tool

graph = graph_tool.Graph(directed=False)
graph.add_vertex(10)
subgraph = graph_tool.GraphView(graph, graph.get_vertices())

print(graph.get_vertices())
print(subgraph.get_vertices())
```

The output is:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I thought a GraphView was supposed to act like a subgraph induced on the specified vertices (so in the case of my sample code, the entire set of vertices). So why does a GraphView omit the 0th vertex?

Or, if this is actually a bug in graph_tool, what would be a good way to work around it, provided I wanted to work with subgraphs that include the 0th vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted the documentation in your answer, but it seems you did not read it carefully enough (emphasis added):

> The argument g must be an instance of a Graph class. If specified, vfilt and efilt select which vertices and edges are filtered, respectively. These parameters can either be a **boolean-valued** PropertyMap or a ndarray, which specify which vertices/edges are selected, or an unary function that returns True if a given vertex/edge is to be selected, or False otherwise.

If you pass a property map or an array, it must be **boolean valued**, not a list of vertices. This means it must have the form `[True, False, False, True, ... ]`, where `True` means  the corresponding vertex is kept, otherwise it's filtered out. That is why the vertex with index 0 (i.e. False) is removed from your example, and all remaining ones are kept.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I did read the documentation carefully, however. The most correct interpretation of what is written is that the descriptor "boolean-valued" really only applies to "PropertyMap." If you want it to apply to both "PropertyMap" and "ndarray" it needs to be "can either be a boolean-valued PropertyMap or ndarray." It's a small difference of wording, but it legitimately does change the meaning. I assumed it was supposed to be an integer array because no type was specified, and the library represents vertex sets as integer arrays in every other case I've seen.

Comment: @trevorKirkby Ok, I get the issue. I will update the documentation to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

So I found a workaround. From the documentation of GraphView:

> The argument g must be an instance of a Graph class. If specified,
>   vfilt and efilt select which vertices and edges are filtered,
>   respectively. These parameters can either be a boolean-valued
>   PropertyMap or a ndarray, which specify which vertices/edges are
>   selected, or an unary function that returns True if a given
>   vertex/edge is to be selected, or False otherwise.

So the vertex mask can also be specified by a unary function that says whether or not the vertex is part of the subgraph:

```
def get_subgraph(graph, vertices):
    f = lambda x: x in vertices
    return graph_tool.GraphView(graph, f)
```

And, somehow, this version actually works!

```
subgraph = get_subgraph(graph, graph.get_vertices())
print(graph.get_vertices())
print(subgraph.get_vertices())
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

So it's not actually *impossible* to make a GraphView that includes 0 as a vertex, it just apparently doesn't work if you try to do it with a numpy array.

This answer works for me, but I would still be interested if anyone has a better workaround (especially since this one makes it much slower to return the subgraph for a large graph), or if somebody knows why this odd behavior arises in the first place.

EDIT:

This implementation leverages numpy to calculate the vertex mask instead of the native python "in" operation, and is therefore much faster for larger graphs:

```
def get_subgraph(graph, vertices):
    property_map = graph.new_vertex_property("bool")
    property_map.a = np.isin(graph.get_vertices(), vertices)
    return graph_tool.GraphView(graph, property_map)
```